# Running Webdriver in Online Python Plaform( Jupyter lab online, Google Colab etc.)

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, webdriver, google-colaboratory

I am able to run Selinium webdriver on my local python IDE to scrape web data, but I wanted to implement it on a online python IDE such as Jupyuter lab online or Google Colab, but the chromedriver.exe path is causing an issue  on online tools and the code is not executing. I had the following code on Jupyter lab online and google colab:

```
import os
import sys
os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
```

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = '/home/jovyan/demo/chromedriver.exe' )

browser.get('https://www.youtube.com/')
```

[I get the following error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAfNP.png)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-5510b62cb210> in <module>
      1 from selenium import webdriver
----> 2 browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = '/home/jovyan/demo/chromedriver.exe' )
      3 
      4 browser.get('https://www.youtube.com/' class="ansi-blue-fg">)

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py in __init__(self, executable_path, port, options, service_args, desired_capabilities, service_log_path, chrome_options, keep_alive)
     71             service_args=service_args,
     72             log_path=service_log_path)
---> 73         self.service.start()
     74 
     75         try:

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py in start(self)
     74                                             stdout=self.log_file,
     75                                             stderr=self.log_file,
---> 76                                             stdin=PIPE)
     77         except TypeError:
     78             raise

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, encoding, errors, text)
    798                                 c2pread, c2pwrite,
    799                                 errread, errwrite,
--> 800                                 restore_signals, start_new_session)
    801         except:
    802             # Cleanup if the child failed starting.

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, restore_signals, start_new_session)
   1549                         if errno_num == errno.ENOENT:
   1550                             err_msg += ': ' + repr(err_filename)
-> 1551                     raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
   1552                 raise child_exception_type(err_msg)
   1553 

OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/home/jovyan/demo/chromedriver.exe'
```

Please let me know if you have any solutions to resolve this issue or any other python platform as the further part of my project hinges on this webdriver.

Answer (score 0):

to run scripts in `Google colab`, I always use the below script, and have never faced any issues, so far. Also it will be only in `headless mode`, **no GUI.**

also you do not give the `executable path` like you have given in **your post**.

```
!pip install selenium
!apt-get update 
!apt install chromium-chromedriver

from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
browser =webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
browser.get('https://www.youtube.com/')
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment. I had previously tried the above code in collab and but wanted the output in GUI and not headless. Could you suggest how to process the GUI in colab?

Comment: @NikhilShukla : As of now collab is restricted to run in only headless mode, it would not run in GUI.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem - the solution for me was to run Anaconda and install all the packages needed for that.

Google colab can't run a webdriver without being headerless, but Anaconda can do this easily!

There are tutorials which exist to help with this, such as
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SsXcyoevkV0

Comment: Please post detailed answer and then references.